# How do I add my own custom content to drupal 7 region?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

If I want to change the content of the footer for $page['footer'] where do I change it?  Im not talking about messing with the .info files.  I dont know why its so hard to find!

Edit:  If I am at on a page.tpl.php file and I do "print render($page['footer'])" how can I configure what is in the $page['footer'] variable to any html I want?

Comment: Please improve your question. Hard to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You should really read some of the basic [documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation). Footer is a Drupal "region". Regions are populated with blocks.

> [block #](http://drupal.org/glossary#block)
> The boxes visible in the [regions](http://drupal.org/glossary#region) of a Drupal website. Most blocks (e.g., recent forum topics) are generated on-the-fly by various Drupal modules, but they can be created in the administer blocks area of a Drupal site. See the documentation for [more information on blocks](http://drupal.org/documentation/blocks).
>
> [region #](http://drupal.org/glossary#region)
> Defined areas of a page where content can be placed. Basic regions include: Header, Footer, Content, Left sidebar, Right Sidebar. Different themes can [define different regions](http://drupal.org/node/171224) so the options are often different per-site. Content is assigned to regions via [blocks](http://drupal.org/glossary#block). They can be ordered by [weight](http://drupal.org/glossary#weight) within regions to define the order in which they display.

If you want to add special static content to the Footer (e.g., Copyright notice, Admin email), you can create a custom block by visiting Home » Administration » Structure » Blocks (/admin/structure/block) and clicking "Add block" (/admin/structure/block/add).

If you want to display the content of a node in your footer, you may want to use [Node Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock). If you want to display the content of multiple nodes, you may want to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).